# Segmentation fault in the second run of a while loop

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu

I have checked all of the other question but all of them have the segmentation fault when the while loop runs the first time, but the error I am getting is coming from the second run of the while loop which is just blowing my mind

```
printf("\nrecieving1");
while(recievedSelect == 0){
    printf("\nrecieving");
    if ((numbytes=recv(new_fd, menuselect, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) == -1){
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(menuselect); i++){
        if(isdigit(menuselect[i])){
            selected = menuselect[i] - '0';
            recievedSelect = 1;
            printf("\nFrom menu:%s\n", menuselect);
            printf("\nSelection:%d\n", selected);
        }
    }
    recievedSelect = 1;
    printf("\nDone recieving1");
}
printf("\nDone recieving2");
recievedSelect = 0;
```

The first time the program runs, everything goes as planned but when the program loops to this while loop again, it gives segmentation fault after triggering the "Done recieving1" text.

I really don't know why it is doing that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How can your loop run twice? receivedSelect will equal 1 and then the while condition won't be satisfied and it will continue

Comment: the recievedSelect is reset to 0 in the end of the program, then everything reset for another run of the program. it is a game,

Comment: and how is `menuselect` deined?

Comment: char menuselect[2];

Comment: but it is defined just once, it is not redefined inside the while loop.

Comment: well, it is defined as an array of 2 elements, but `recv` can read up to MAXDATASIZE in this array. I think that you are corrupting memory there. You need to define it as `menuselect[MXDATASIZE]`, right?

Comment: @Serge I will try that, thanks

Comment: @Tom Karzes I don't close the program then reopen it, the program it self is a big while loop with this while as a part of that big while loop.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, but it's difficult to understand what it's doing without seeing the entire function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is safer instead of the line:

   > numbytes=recv(new_fd, menuselect, MAXDATASIZE, 0)

use

```
numbytes=recv(new_fd, menuselect, sizeof(menuselect), 0)
```

2. The for() loop should iterate only the received data, so instead of:

   > for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(menuselect); i++)

use

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbytes; i++)
```

3. recv() returns a binary data (not NUL-terminated), so instead of:

   > printf("\nFrom menu:%s\n", menuselect);

use

```
printf("\nFrom menu:%c\n", menuselect[0]);
```

Comment: For some reason, this solved the for loop problem. Thank you.